# When to use present form for a past thing?

Tags: grammar-identification, lingua-latina-per-se-illustrata

I'm reading the passage about the Trojan War in *Lingua Latina per se Illustrata: Roma Aeterna* (Ch. 37).

The verbs are mostly in past forms (*imperf.*, *perf.* or *plup.*), but in line 140~142:

> Aenēās vērō, ... atque dēfēnsōribus sēsē adiungit.

the verb ***adiungit*** is in *pres.* form. Is there any reason for it?

(I find the following sentences also have present verbs)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called the historical present, and its typically used to make the action more vivid. See *Allen and Greenough* §469.

> The present in lively narrative is often used for the Historical Perfect.
>
> ***Affertur nūntius Syrācūsās; curritur ad praetōrium; Cleomenēs in pūblico esse nōn audet; inclūditsē domī.*** (Verr. 5.92)
> *The news is brought to Syracuse; they run to headquarters; Cleomenes does not venture to be abroad; he shuts himself up at home.*

See also this thread on the topic: [tense fluctuation in Latin narrative](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/tense-fluctuation-in-latin-narrative)