# Frequent changes of tense in Caesar

Tags: tenses, praesens-historicum

I am a little bit mystified by the frequent changes of tense in Caesar's prose and am wondering what the rationale is. Should I take from this that it is perfectly fine to just switch back and forth from the present, perfect and imperfect whenever I feel like it, or is there some rule to it?

For example, if we take the following passage from the Commentary on the Gallic War, Section 3:

```
10 His rebus adducti et auctoritate Orgetorigis permoti constituerunt  PERFECT
11     ea quae ad proficiscendum pertinerent comparare,                IMPERFECT SUBJUNCTIVE
14         ut in itinere copia frumenti suppeteret,                    IMPERFECT SUBJUNCTIVE
16 Ad eas res conficiendas biennium sibi satis esse duxerunt           PERFECT
17 in tertium annum profectionem lege confirmant.                      PRESENT
18 Ad eas res conficiendas Orgetorix deligitur.                        PRESENT
19 Is sibi legationem ad civitates suscepit.                           PERFECT
20 In eo itinere persuadet Castico, Catamantaloedis filio, Sequano,    PRESENT
22     ut regnum in civitate sua occuparet,                            IMPERFECT SUBJUNCTIVE
23     quod pater ante habuerat;                                       PLUPERFECT 
25         ut idem conaretur persuadet eique filiam suam in matrimonium dat.   IMPERFECT SUBJUNCTIVE and PRESENT
26 Perfacile factu esse illis probat conata perficere,                     PRESENT
27     propterea quod ipse suae civitatis imperium obtenturus esset:       FUTURE INFINITIVE
28     non esse dubium, quin totius Galliae plurimum Helvetii possent;     IMPERFECT SUBJUNCTIVE
29 se suis copiis suoque exercitu illis regna conciliaturum confirmat.     PRESENT
30 Hac oratione adducti inter se fidem et iusiurandum dant,                PRESENT
31     et regno occupato .... sperant.                                     PRESENT
```

So, as an example of just one of the oddities in this passage, in clause 19 he uses the perfect ("He himself undertook an embassy to the nations"), but then in the very next sentence instead of using the perfect, he uses the present ("On this journey he persuades Castico..."). I would have expected *persuasit*, not *persuadet*. Contrarily, he uses the present in the clause before, number 18.

It just seems completely random whether he is using the perfect or present or imperfect.

This is not a duplicate because, because first of all, the previous question about changes of tense is 6 years old and went unanswered, probably because it was vague. Also, the guy was asking about composition in general, not understanding a specific text.

Comment: Surely the *imperfect subjunctive* isn't random in the sentences you mentioned?

Comment: @brianpck The imperfect subjunctive is used more consistently.

Comment: See also [this link](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/tense-fluctuation-in-latin-narrative), which, if you look again, does have an answer, one that is upvoted and accepted.